# Handling Special Characters (¦)

Tags: c#

I'm a bit lost on how to read and write to/from text files in C# when special characters are present. I'm writing a simple script that does some cleanup on a .txt data file which contains the '¦' character as its delimiter.

```
 foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"path\raw txt","*.txt"))
            {
                string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);              
                contents = contents.Replace("¦", ",");
                File.WriteAllText(file.Replace("raw txt", "txt"), contents);
            }
```

However, when I open the txt file in Notepad++, the delimeter is now �. What exactly is going on? What even is this characters (¦) encoding / how would I determine that? I've tried adding things like:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(file, Encoding.UTF8);
File.WriteAllText(file.Replace("raw txt", "txt"), contents, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)"

Comment: I believe Notepad++ shows most special characters like that.

Comment: @James_Parsons before running the script, the delimiter shows up fine in Notepad++

Comment: Where did the file come from? Basically, you need to know its encoding and make sure you read it appropriately.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? It's a perfectly good question from someone who has not had to deal with character encoding (which is lots of people). Can be helpful to other people struggling with similar issues. So, +1

Comment: @logan_gabriel ok, are you sure your encoding is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is now working correctly by switching the encoding to 'default' when both reading/writing.

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(file, Encoding.Default);
File.WriteAllText(file.Replace("raw txt", "txt"), contents, Encoding.Default);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change encoding of Notepad to UTF-8